# Swift method doesn't override any method from its superclass

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2

I am relatively new to Swift and I am following some basic tutorials but I seem to be having a problem with some methods which attempt to allow the user to press return to minimise the keyboard or to click off the keyboard and the keyboard will disappear, I understand why I am receiving these errors but have no clue how to go about fixing it, I feel something may have been changed in the newer version of Swift I am using as he is using an older version than me, could anyone possibly explain how to go about fixing these two errors please? Any help would be greatly appreciated here is my source code: (First error, value of type 'viewController' has no member 'text' and secondly, touchesBegan method does not override any method from its superclass)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

   label.text = textArea.text

}

@IBOutlet weak var textArea: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.text.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}

}
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, make sure you create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You must implement UITextfieldDelegate on your view controller in order to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems here, based on the images you posted:

1) The method touhesBegan you are using [is not correct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:):

Correct one:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

Yours:

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

I think you want a delegate for the UITextField, so this one is not corerct: touchesBegan is a method for the UIReponder delegate and not for UITextFieldDelegate.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html) you can find the reference for the UITextFieldDelegate.

2) the variable `text` doesn't exists in your code. I think you wanted to use `textArea` instead.

Hope this can help you, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was indeed using the wrong function, thanks a lot my friend :) Both issues fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In your case change following thing:

instead of :

```
self.text.delegate = self
```

change :

```
self.textArea.delegate = self


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }
```

And for delegate add like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Oh my I knew it would be something simple, thanks first error solved. I have removed the override keyword but it says 'Method touchesBegan with objective-C selector touchesBegan:withEvent conflicts with method touchesBegan from superclass' which sounds like it needs to override the other method

Comment: @DavidThomlinson check and i have modified:

Comment: You need to change method  params in touchesBegan.